# GPS data missing from some iPhone photos but present in others

Tags: ios, gps, photo, exif

I was looking back at some photos and videos I took on my iPhone 6 one evening in February 2016 - and noticed that there were some major discrepancies in whether the file had GPS data or not. I took 19 photos/videos in total, of which 2/3 had GPS data available. Below is a list of the files and whether or not they had GPS data (file names are from Dropbox CameraUpload):

**1.**     2016-02-17 20.34.18.jpg   -  has GPS data
**2.**     2016-02-17 20.34.19.jpg   -  has GPS data
**3.**     2016-02-17 20.48.30.mov -  no GPS data
**4.**     2016-02-17 21.55.10.jpg   -  no GPS data
**5.**     2016-02-17 21.55.11.jpg   -  no GPS data
**6.**     2016-02-17 21.55.15.jpg   -  has GPS data
**7.**     2016-02-17 21.55.16.jpg   -  has GPS data
**8.**     2016-02-17 21.55.20.jpg   -  has GPS data
**9.**     2016-02-17 22.02.57.jpg   -  has GPS data
**10.**   2016-02-17 22.02.58.jpg   -  has GPS data
**11.**   2016-02-17 22.03.04.jps   -  has GPS data
**12.**   2016-02-17 22.06.57.jpg   -  no GPS data
**13.**   2016-02-17 22.06.59.jpg   -  no GPS data
**14.**   2016-02-17 22.08.31.mov -  no GPS data
**15.**   2016-02-17 22.12.14.jpg   -  has GPS data
**16.**   2016-02-17 22.12.14.jpg   -  has GPS data
**17.**   2016-02-17 22.12.17.jpg   -  has GPS data
**18.**   2016-02-17 22.12.42.jpg   -  has GPS data
**19.**   2016-02-17 22.20.41.mov -  has GPS data

I've used [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to look into the files in more detail and tried to find any obvious differences, including whether the files are:

- photos or videos - **no correlation**
- recorded from the front or rear camera - **all taken with rear camera**
- taken in portrait or landscape - **no correlation**
- captured using the side volume button or button within the Camera app - **have tested this separately; no correlation**
- captured from a locked or unlocked home screen - **have tested this separately; no correlation**

None of which has proven fruitful.

There just doesn't seem to be any logic behind it - some photos do have GPS **(9)**, some don't **(13)** - and it's the same with movies: **(3)** is a movie file with no GPS data, and yet **(19)** is a movie that does have GPS data - it appears completely random.

What's also interesting is that there are two photos **(5)** and **(6)** that were taken 4 seconds apart - the first **(5)** doesn't have GPS data, and yet the second **(6)** does.

If there's anyone that can suggest a logical reason behind this then I'd be very grateful to know!

Comment: Sometimes if the device doesn't have a GPS signal/lock, it will omit the metadata from the image.

Comment: Is it a programming question? Did you take these photos/videos with an application that you wrote?

Comment: @DrewNoakes - if it's as simple explanation as that, that's fine - it was just really bugging me not knowing. Your suggestion could explain the difference between (5) and (6) - as it may not have had the 'lock' for image (5), but locked in before (6) was taken. Thanks

Comment: @TDG no, it's not a programming question - but as I saw a load of other GPS/exif/iPhone related questions in here I thought it was the best place to post